# Error: expected ')' before numeric constant (fwrite)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fwrite

I have searched around the internet for a solution, but I still cannot find it. So I signed up here, hopefully some of you could help me. I am still learning C, so pardon if it is a stupid question. I've recently made a code, and everything worked fine, until I decided to add an fwrite, here's what it looks like:

```
char str[] = "Test.";
fwrite(str, 1, sizeof(str), Console);
```

I tried to compile it, and the compiler gives me an error:

```
Main.c:57:13: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly is `Console`?

Comment: replace Console by stdout

Comment: You might want to replace `Console` with `stdout` and `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Compile your file with `-E` flag and look at that line to understand what the compiler truly sees.

Comment: If I replace "Console" with "stdout" it gives me the same error

Comment: So please which character is line 57, column 13?!

Comment: fwrite(str, 1, sizeof(str), Console);

Comment: The problem must be somewhere before those lines, please include more code, even the whole source file if that is possible.

Comment: ... and where is column 13?

Comment: alk: Count 13 characters from the left... or guess what is the numeric constant on the fwrite line.

Geeh: Post the whole of Main.c if it is short enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
char str[] = "Test.";
fwrite(&str, sizeof(char), sizeof(str), stdout);
```

Although, I think the problem might be due to an open parentheses somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Although, I think the problem might lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try stdout in place of Console.

Comment: If I replace "Console" with "stdout" it gives me the same error

Comment: it shouldn't have shown this error even if you use Console. It will show you the error : undefined symbol console. So the error you got is due to some other mistake in your code.